# Providing endpoint URI to server-side rendered app

Tags: server-side-rendering

This code initializes an Apollo client for interaction with a GraphQL backend:

```
function create(initialState?: any) {
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
    return new ApolloClient({
        connectToDevTools: isBrowser,
        ssrMode: !isBrowser,
        link: new HttpLink({
            uri: "https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            fetch: !isBrowser && fetch
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
    })
}
```

where `APPNAME` is replaced with the name of the Heroku app that hosts said backend. However, when the URI written as a simple string is replaced by an environment variable such as `process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT`, requests are not sent to the correct URI anymore but to the `/graphql` endpoint on the local server. That is most certainly caused by the app being a server-side rendered Next.js app, since the request has then chances of being sent by the client rather than the server, and `process` doesn't exist on client-side.

Therefore the question is: what is a simple way for the app to get the endpoint URI from something like an environment variable or a file hosted on server-side?

I did some research and a solution could be hosting a microservice locally in order to host a JSON file that would contain the URI, as recommended [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4552). Would there be a solution that doesn't require such overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by adding a hidden HTML tag inside the `<head>` like this:

```
<p style={hidden} id="graphql_endpoint">
    {process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT}
</p>
```

with `hidden` defined to `{ display: "none" }`, and then retrieving it when creating the Apollo client like this:

```
uri: isBrowser
    ? document.getElementById("graphql_endpoint").innerHTML
    : process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
```